# Implement a Angular Interceptor for network state detection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an angular application and i want it to work that way for each http request:

1. Don't send the request if there is no network and throw error
2. Cancel the request and throw error if the network state was changed to "offline"
3. Cancel the request and throw error if there is no response after X milliseconds
4. Return the response if everything went ok

For right now I've created this service that gives me network states:

```
export class ConnectionStateService {
  private connectionState = new Subject<ConnectionState>()
  private onlineObservable = fromEvent(window, 'online')
  private offlineObservable = fromEvent(window, 'offline')

  constructor() {
    this.onlineObservable.subscribe(event => this.connectionState.next(ConnectionState.ONLINE))
    this.offlineObservable.subscribe(event => this.connectionState.next(ConnectionState.OFFLINE))
  }

  getConnectionState() {
    return this.connectionState.asObservable()
  }

  getOfflineUpdates() {
    return this.offlineObservable
  }

  getCurrentConnectionState() {
    return navigator.onLine ? ConnectionState.ONLINE : ConnectionState.OFFLINE
  }
}
```

And implemented this Http Interceptor:

```
const MAX_REQUEST_TIME = 10000

intercept(req, next) {
    if (this.connectionStateService.getCurrentConnectionState() === ConnectionState.OFFLINE)
      return throwError(new HttpErrorResponse({error: 'Internet is required'}))

    return race(
      this.connectionStateService.getOfflineUpdates().pipe(mapTo(false)),
      timeout(MAX_REQUEST_TIME),
      next.handle(req)
    )
  }
```

So far the interceptor handles cases 1 and 4 but for some reason `timeout(MAX_REQUEST_TIME)`
doesn't work, and also `this.connectionStateService.getOfflineUpdates().pipe(mapTo(false))` doesn't emit `false` when i disconnect from the network after the request was sent. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `next.handle()` will always *win*, because when the request in sent, besides the response/error, that observable will also [emit a `Sent` event](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L326):

```js
// Fire the request, and notify the event stream that it was fired.
xhr.send(reqBody!);
observer.next({type: HttpEventType.Sent});
```

What you could do in this case is to use the `filter` operator:

```js
race(
  this.connectionStateService.getOfflineUpdates().pipe(mapTo(false)),
  timeout(MAX_REQUEST_TIME),
  next.handle(req).pipe(filter(e => e.type !== HttpEventType.Sent))
)
```